# Trouble Completing City Selecting tool

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy

I am working on trying to create a tool which would allow me to type in any city name (in this cause European cities), and zoom into that city. My script will run but nothing is selected. I don't know  what I'm missing.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import mapping
#set workspace
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
#set the dataframe
fc = ("N:/data2016/Lab13/cities.shp")
cities = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "Cities")[0]
#Set local variables
cityName = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

cities_layer = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc, "cities_lyr")
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("cities_layer", "NEW_SELECTION", CITY_NAME = cityName)

arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0].zoomToSelectedFeatures()
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all you just need to use cities from the ListLayers method if the Cities layer is already in your map.  Do not use the layer created by the MakeFeatureLayer if that is the case.

Second, you have not created a proper selection string for the SelectLayerByAttribute method.  It should be:

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(cities, "NEW_SELECTION", "CITY_NAME = '{0}'".format(cityName))
```

Comment: +1 beat me by a minute, and nice catch of the ListLayers and the MakeFeatureLayer